# solaris simple bash script

Tags: bash, solaris

I'm trying to execute this simple script in solaris. 
I want to sort(numeric) the filenames of the files in source directory and copy the file one by one to another directory. And, I want to print a message after copying every 100 files.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0

for i in `ls | sort -n`
do 
 cp $i ../target
 count = $((count+1))
 if[ $count%100 -eq 0 ] 
 then
    echo $count files copied
    sleep 1
 fi

done
```

this is not working. I tried different things after searching in net.
I get errors like these -

syntax error at line 8: '(' unexpected.
syntax error at line 10: 'then' unexpected.
syntax error at line 13: 'fi' unexpected etc.

What is the problem with this script?

bash version - GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count=$((count+1))`

```
if [ `echo $count % 100 | bc` -eq 0 ]
```

Make these corrections.

Edit: Please try

```
count=`expr $count + 1`
```

Comment: Thanks. `count=$((count+1))` throws this error syntax error at line 8: count=$' unexpected. `if` worked.

Comment: `count=\`expr $count + 1\`` and `count=\`echo "$count + 1" | bc\`` posted by idfah both worked.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem with the script is spacing. You have spaces where you shouldn't have them:

```
(wrong)  count = $((count+1))
(right)  count=$((count+1))
(better) ((count++))
```

and you're missing spaces where you need them:

```
(wrong)  if[ $count%100 -eq 0 ]
(right)  if [ $((count % 100)) -eq 0 ]
(better) if ((count % 100 == 0))
```

`count = $((count+1))` tries to run the command `count` passing it two arguments, `=` and the value of `count+1`. `if[ ...` tries to run the command `if[` because `[` is a valid word character; it doesn't automatically start a new token.

Having said all that, I'm puzzled by the `unexpected (` error message. Could your bash be too old to recognize `$((` syntax? Possibly. It's a very old bash.

Comment: Thanks. Got these errors - count++: not found,  syntax error at line 8: `count=$' unexpected etc.. For some reason these things are not working. maybe this is very old bash?

Comment: @KarthiPk: It's quite an old bash. I suspect it doesn't have arithmetic expansion. Does `let count++` work?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few errors here.  First, you need double quotes around `$i` in case they have special characters.

Second, you shouldn't ever use

```
for i in `ls | sort -n`
```

Instead, try the following

```
ls -1 | sort -n | while read i
```

Third, change your if statement to

```
if ((count%5 == 0))
```

The `((` syntax is bash is made just for integer math.

Fourth, change your counter increment to

```
((count++))
```

This is more concise.  Also, the space in your version may break things.  Remember, spaces matter.

Comment: Thanks. `while` worked. `if ((count%5 == 0))` and `((count++))` gives these errors - count%5: not found and count++: not found

Comment: Hmm, probably a really old version of bash.  You could try ``count=`echo "$count + 1" | bc` `` and ``if [ `echo "$count % 100 | bc` -eq 0]``

Comment: Strange, I think arithmetic should work in bash 3.  Do you have `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script?  Do you have posix mode on?  Check with `set -o`

Comment: I used to use solaris 10 and don't recall having problems with `((`